# React warning for missing `onChange` handle when using `onKeyDown` instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, onkeydown

React is giving me [this warning](https://i.imgur.com/8SRkRN6.png) for two of my input elements.

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
```

However, in my implementation I'm currently using `onKeyDown` rather than `onChange` to achieve essentially the same thing. See my current implementation below:

```
function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <main>
    // ...
      <input type="text" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} value={value} />
    // ...
    </main>
  );

  function handleKeyDown(e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    if (e.key === "enter") return handle() // Must be called on enter press, cannot use onChange for this as that triggers when the element is clicked away from
    if (e.key.length === 1) return setValue(value + e.key); // input is not case-sensitive so no need to check for shift key or caps lock
    if (e.key === "Backspace") {
      if (e.ctrlKey) return setValue("");
      else return setValue(value.slice(0, -1);
  }
}
```

I understand it would prefer I use onchange, but that removes the ability to handle on pressing enter. Whilst it's an option to simply write both `onChange` and `onKeyDown`, doesn't this overcomplicate for no reason?

Can I safely ignore this issue? Is there a way of suppressing just this error message so I don't have to deal with it whilst building/debugging with the console open? Should I simply set the input field to `readonly` (my current implementation still works, at least on chrome)?

Edit: I've defined the input as `readOnly` to prevent this issue. It's not exactly a very good solution as it means the keyboard won't pop up for on-screen-keyboards (not a priority to support mobile browsers as a mobile app is planned) but it seems to be the only way to resolve this effectively.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the app's scope is realistically for corp internal usage only, so edge cases (e.g. text-to-speech, mobile browsers, etc) aren't exactly a priority. No harm in adapting to such cases if it's not going to negatively affect other areas though!

Comment: This might be hacky, but can you not just do `onChange={()=>{}}` to remove the error and make it not read-only?

I feel onKeyDown is not the right way though as it will fire on typing text into the input.  Can the keyPress stuff not be done with eventlistners and useEffect instead?

Comment: @VayneValerius That's actually a much better hacky solution, cheers for that! However I've realised you're right, I was handling onChange incorrectly in my setstate that was causing errors (hence why I changed to keypress). I've changed it to `onChange={handleChange}` (which essentially just calls `setValue`, and changed my onKeyDown to only call `handle()` on enter, and removed the rest. Cheers for the help!